# Create VPC Endpoint for AWS Cost explorer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

Hi I am trying to use AWS cost explorer API's to get billing usage, I tried to find a VPC Endpoint for this but was unable to find one.
Is there a way to create a Custom Endpoint for AWS services ?
(P.S. : Please don't suggest to use a NAT or Internet gateway)

Answer (score 2):

AWS Cost Explorer does not have a VPC endpoint.

You can check supported services for VPC endpoints [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html):

If you don't want to use NAT nor Internet gateway, you could maybe proxy to the explorer using your own [VPC endpoint services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/endpoint-service.html). This would require a second VPC with access to the cost explorer.

Alternatively, you could create [private API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html) Gateway, with `AWS` integration to the cost explorer REST API.

Comment: I tried creating a VPC endpoint for API Gateway execute-api from the link that you mentioned, it did not worked out for me. Did it worked for you ?

Comment: Plus I checked one more thing AWS Cost explorer has a service enpoint fixed as ce.us-east-1.amazonaws.com, it doesn't change according to regions. So, I did not think VPC endpoint will work here.

Comment: @AnuragRawat I used private API endpoints for Kinesis, but not cost explorer. So you are left with poxying all requests somehow if you can't accept nat gateway.